# How mock class in Unit Test for a Action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, automated-tests, moq

I'm implementing Unit Test on existing software.
These software is in ASP.NET MVC, and I want test the return of a Action, of a Controller.

But in this Action a I have the code:

```
 public ActionResult EditProfile(
        string accountId = null,
        string partnership = null,
        AccountType? subscriptionType = null,
        bool forcePartnerUpdate = false)
    {
        var model = new EditProfileModel();
        var account = _authUser.Account;  
        var catalogClient = new CatalogService.CatalogClient(Request.Cookies, Globals.CatalogURL);
```

The problem is because the last line : "new CatalogService.CatalogService()"

I'm using this class in other part of Action:

```
model.ListBrands = new List<Brands>();
model.ListAvailableBrands = new List<Brands>();
model.ListSubscribedBrands = new List<Brands>();
var brands = catalogClient.GetBrandsWithManufacturer();
```

So, How I can mock this for tests?

I have thought in abstract for a interface and send how a parameter in action, but I don't have the Request in my NInjectModule to IoC and in other codes this class has other parameters, so I think I can't do IoC.

How I can mock this with moq?

Thank you for help.

Comment: you can´t, unless you inject the `CatalogClient` into your class.

Comment: Are you using any IoC controller? In that case you can use dependency injection and inject CatalogClient in your controller class

Comment: I'm using Ninject to IoC in my software and the Resolver of Ninject is registered in Global.asax.
In the Global.asax I don't have the "Request" (Cookies is a parameter for this class) to do a IoC of this class.

Comment: Why does `CatalogClient` need access to the cookies anyways? Seems like you may need to add some more abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought and tested a lot and now I got to do the mock for my tests.

First, I've created a "Factory" to my class:

```
public interface ICatalogClientFactory
{
    ICatalogClient Create(HttpCookieCollection cookies, string catalogUrl);
}

public class CatalogClientFactory : ICatalogClientFactory
{
    public ICatalogClient Create(HttpCookieCollection cookies, string catalogUrl)
    {
        return new CatalogClient(cookies, catalogUrl);
    }
}
```

Than, this Interface I've registered in the NinjectModule and set this in the constructor of Controller. So, I'm calling in my actions with this code:

```
  ICatalogClientFactory _catalogClientFactory = catalogClientFactory;
  var clientCatalog = _catalogClientFactory.Create(Request.Cookies, Globals.CatalogURL);
```

Now, I can mock "ICatalogClientFactory" and "ICatalogClient" to use in unit tests.